# SmtpClient.SendAsync() not receiving all messages I sent

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I've just written some test code looking at the System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient sending identical messages to myself.

```
int numClients = 10;
List<SmtpClient> mailClients = new List<SmtpClient>();
for (int i = 0; i < numClients; i++) {
    mailClients.Add(new SmtpClient(smtpHost));
}

MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("myAddress@eg.com", "myAddress@eg.com", "test message", "" );
foreach (SmtpClient c in mailClients) {
    c.SendAsync(msg, null);
}
```

This is all fine and executes without any problems except that I only receive *'n - 1'* messages.
i.e. If I send 10 messages I only recieve 9 in my inbox.   If I send 50 I only receive 49 etc.

Note: If I change the code to use a blocking Send then I will always receive the right number of messages.
e.g.

```
foreach (SmtpClient c in mailClients) {
    c.Send(msg);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few observations that may help:

- Only create one SmtpClient.
- Create multiple messages instead.
- SmtpClient implements IDisposable.  Wrap it in *using*.
- MailMessage also implements IDisposable.

I suspect you may be running into a bug/issue with multiple SmtpClient instances that all wrap the same SMTP server.  Using a single instance may resolve the issue.

**UPDATE**

Per MSDN:

> After calling SendAsync, you must wait for the e-mail transmission to complete before attempting to send another e-mail message using Send or SendAsync.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h.aspx

So given your situation, there is almost no benefit to using SendAsync over Send.  Your loop is probably stomping on something since you do not wait for the previous SendAsync to complete.

Here are a few thoughts:

- SendAsync will perform almost the same as Send if you are sending a bunch of emails.  Just use Send.
- If you need parallel sending, use a Producer/Consumer pattern.  One (or more) producing threads dump stuff into a queue to send, and multiple consuming threads each use one SmtpClient to send messages.  This pattern is amazingly simple to implement with a BlockingCollection.  See the example in MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx
- If you use enough threads, your SMTP server will be the bottleneck.  Be aware of when you are overloading it.

Comment: Sure thing.  Using only one SmtpClient means I need to wait for each message to be sent before sending the next one.  Also, this test code is a gross simplification of an issue I'm actually having, where I won't be able to get away from the fact there are multiple SmtpClients hitting the same server at once.

Comment: @drew: Try getting it to work with a single SmtpClient and multiple messages, and properly disposing of IDisposable things.  Once that works, get multiple clients working.  In other words, dissect the problem.

Comment: Added some more thoughts and a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. My understanding is your quote from MSDN applies to each SmtpClient individually, and that's fair enough. I would've thought though that each smtp client would use its own thread to do its own Async sending (effectively as you suggest via Produce/Consume).  I'm happy using a blocking Send, just trying to understand the reason as to why the SendAsync would only transmit _'n - 1'_ messages

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?